# Change IDs and Change Order?

Tags: admin-panel, page-content, id

I'm working with 2.3.3 and I can't figure out how to change the order of items. We have a "downloads" page, which uses a "manage downloads" module (via the dashboard). When I add a new download, it seems to be assigned an ID # by default and that number dictates the order in which it is displayed on the site. This seems to be the same for our "manage brand" module as well. I'm assuming, IDs dictate the order in which items are displayed but how can I change the order or change the ID #? The ability to rearrange items in what is basically a list seems basic but I can't figure it out. Can any of this be done via Admin/Dashboard or is this something that has to been done in the developer environment? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to archive, describe in some more details?

Comment: Our site has a "downloads" page and a "line card" (listing brands). Seems like these two pages are using the respective "manage downloads" and "manage brands" modules to suck in the content. It also seems that it is using the content "ID" to determine the order in which it appears.

Comment: The ID will be the auto increment ID from the database. Changing that is generally a bad idea. Does either of the modules give you a sort order option? And is the display you are looking to change the order of in the admin or on the frontend?

Comment: Yes, there is an option to sort within the module but it doesn't affect anything on the frontend. I'm actually fine with not changing IDs but at the very least there must be a way to sort either alphabetical or manually. I would assume this is basic functionality but then again, I am somewhat new to the Magento world and still trying to grasp its shortcomings.